# ICSDrawer and Navigation Controller is Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have used ICSDrawerController for my Side View Controller .
But when I set my Centre and Left View Controller to my ICSDrawerController all the remaining Navigations stopped working.

```
  ICSDrawerController *drawC = [[ICSDrawerController alloc]initWithLeftViewController:side centerViewController:viewOne];
```

Here ViewOne is my Centre and Side is my Side View Controller.

```
ICSDrawerController *drawC = [[ICSDrawerController alloc]initWithLeftViewController:side centerViewController:_nav];
```

When I give navigation instead of viewOne my navigations work but Humburger button which calls my side view controller doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your relevant code here? e.g. the `Humburger` calls your side view controller